# How do I log Custom Messages to the Execution Report in SSIS 2012

Tags: ssis-2012

When an exception occurs in the execution of a task, for instance a lookup task fails to find a match, I want to report that exception and the value it was looking for in the Execution Report. How do I do that? Is there a more appropriate way to do that in SSIS?

Answer (score 2):

Without actually doing the work, I think you should use the No Match output, [What´s the difference between Error output and "No match Output" in Lookup transformation SSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13730531/whats-the-difference-between-error-output-and-no-match-output-in-lookup-trans) , to pass the rows to a Script Task to log a warning, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136054.aspx , and you should be able to see the list of warnings in the Execution Report, http://www.rad.pasfu.com/index.php?/archives/78-SSIS-Catalog-Part-5-Logging-and-Execution-Reports.html .

Comment: Been away. I will try this within the next few days. Thanks shriop!